# Add Textinput Comonent to Text Area as a Text

Tags: apache-flex

Please Anyone Suggest Me..

**I have an problem that i want to add textinput or Any Component to TextArea Component...**

Thanks,

Comment: Why you want to add  textinput or Any Component to `TextArea` Component? you can use containers(Canvas,HBox,VBox etc) right?

Answer (score 0):

The Flex [TextArea](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/TextArea.html) component is not a container, so it is unusual to try to add children to it.  You probably can do so, but you will have to re-write the TextArea's layout code and positioning to add your new component.  You'll find this code in the [TextAreaSkin](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/skins/spark/TextAreaSkin.html).